# Pushing to a stack that uses a Linked List in java

Tags: java, linked-list, stack, push

Question on what exactly I'm supposed to be passing into that push method. I want to push the info in a series of .txt files to my wikis stack inside my main method so that I can later pop it and work with it. Here is the error netbeans is giving me:

no suitable method found for push()
    method FancyStack.push(FancyStack>) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method FancyStack.push(Node) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Please let me know if anyone would like additional info.

```
FancyStack<Node<WikiObjects>> wikis = new FancyStack<Node<WikiObjects>>();
FancyStack<Node<WikiObjects>> titles = new FancyStack<Node<WikiObjects>>();
WikiEdits edits = new WikiEdits(args);
String titleName = edits.title();
String editID = edits.editID();


    while(edits.moveToNext() != false){

        wikis.push();
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is my FancyStack

```
import java.util.*;

public class FancyStack<E> {

//pieced together linked list
private int cnt;
private Node<E> head;
public FancyStack<E> stack;
public FancyStack<E> s;

public FancyStack() {
    head = null;
    cnt = 0;
}

public void push(E item) { //THIS WORKS
    //your average kind of pushing an item onto stack
    Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(item);
    newNode.setLink(head);
    head = newNode;
    cnt++;
}

public void push(FancyStack<E> s) { //THIS WORKS
    //pushes all elements of FancyStack s into a new stack (this)
    //however stack this is in reverse order from FancyStack<E> s
    if (s.isEmpty()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Empty Stack");
    }

    while (!s.isEmpty()) {
        Node<E> element = s.head;
        this.push(element.getInfo());
        s.pop();
        element = element.getLink();
    }

}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return head == null;
}

public int size() {
    return cnt;
}

public E pop() { //THIS CORRECT
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Stack underflow");
    } else {
        E item = head.item;
        head = head.link;
        cnt--;
        return item;
    }
}

public E peek() { //THIS WORKS
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Stack underflow");
    }
    return head.item;
}

public FancyStack<E> reversed() {
  /*  if (this.isEmpty()) {    // want to test exceotion error with this commented out.
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Empty Stack");
    }*/
    FancyStack<E> newthis = new FancyStack<E>();
    while (!this.isEmpty()) { //elmt short for 'element'
        Node<E> elmt = this.head;
        newthis.push(elmt.getInfo());
        this.pop();
        elmt = elmt.getLink();
    }
    return newthis;

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've specified that `wikis` is a `FancyStack` of `Node<WikiObjects>` objects. You must push a `Node<WikiObjects>` object. `FancyStack` also allows you to push another `FancyStack`. In my opinion, that's a poorly named API, since it doesn't do what it says. Instead of pushing a `FancyStack` it pushes all of the elements from the `FancyStack`. It should be named `pushAll`.

*Edited based on provided FancyStack source*